# Retrieve New user's ID

Tags: users, hooks, user-registration

I'm trying to retrieve the user id of a new user as soon as they're created.  I tried using the hook "user_register" but there appears to be no id in there...maybe it grabs the data before a userID is created?  Anyway, if anyone could recommend a hook that would serve this purpose, I'd appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only argument you get on `user_register` is the user ID.

```
add_action( 'user_register', function( $user_id ) 
{
    echo $user_id;
});
```

Maybe there is an error in your code?

Comment: Huh, that worked quite well.  I was trying to call a separate function with the hook like so: `add_action( 'user_register', 'my_user_register');`  The function, at this point, just accepted the variable: `function my_user_register($user_id);` and echoed it: `echo $user_id`.  Maybe I'm making some sort of php error here, I am quite green (inexperienced) when it comes to web development.  Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong?  Thanks again!

Comment: Never mind, problem solved! I was calling the same function later and overwriting its contents.  Thanks so much!